# Micronoaut ServerStartupEvent callback not called in startup?

Tags: startup, micronaut

Just started to experiment with MN M3. Created a minimal Groovy service with the following code:

```
package test2

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventListener
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.event.ServerStartupEvent


@Singleton
@CompileStatic
class Application implements ApplicationEventListener<ServerStartupEvent> {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Start"
        Micronaut.run(Application.class)
    }

    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(ServerStartupEvent event) {
        println "Boo!"
    }
}
```

I get the "Start" but the startup event callback is never called:

> Start
>
> 10:35:54.066 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup 
>   completed in 897ms. Server Running: http://localhost:32034

I **think** this is the appropriate way to deal with initialization in MN?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out Groovy has its own @Singleton annotation which was used by default. You need to import:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton
```

Might be a good idea to emphasize this somewhere in the docs.

Comment: "Might be a good idea to emphasize this somewhere in the docs." - At https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.0.M4/guide/index.html#groovy is a comment that calls out exactly that.  "Groovy automatically imports groovy.lang.Singleton which can be confusing as it conflicts with javax.inject.Singleton. Make sure you include the javax.inject.Singleton import when declaring a singleton bean to avoid a compilation error.".